# Ace editor : Code validation on specific line

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, validation, ace-editor

I am working on lecture validation code. I want to be able to check a line, get content and validate it, if it is what the user should put.  I am using "for loop" to iterate the process. JSON to set validation process. The issue is the return error does not match. My question is what is the best way to validate code using Ace editor?

**Validation Process (JSON)**

```
  {
"course" : "html",
"count" : 2,
"line" : [8, 9],
"check" : ["My name is", ""],
"error" : ["Please type your name. Start with 'My name is'","Write why  you want to learn HTML"]
}
```

**HTML & Javascript**

```js
var html = ace.edit("html-editor");
 html_option = {
    mode: "ace/mode/javascript",
    theme: "ace/theme/monokai",
    fontSize: "10pt",
    showPrintMargin : false,
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    enableSnippets: true,
    enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
    wrap: true,
    scrollPastEnd: true,
    displayIndentGuides: true,
  };

 html.setOptions(html_option);

//Get the JSON validation file
var fond = $(".json").html();
      fond = JSON.parse(fond);

//Begin validation on Click "Run"
$("#run").on("click", function(){
        $('#run').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Running');
        
        var fond_course = fond.course;
        var fond_count = fond.count;
        
        //Begin error check
        for (var i = 0; i < fond_count; i++) {
          var line = fond.line[i] - 1;
          var error = fond.error[i] ;
          var check = fond.check[i];
          
          var fond_check = html.session.getLine(line);
          
          var patt = new RegExp(check);
            var res = patt.test(fond_check);
          
          //If a specific line is empty
          if(check === null){
            html.gotoLine(line);
            line = line + 1;
            
            //Error function with parameters
            //error_note(true, error, line);
          }
          //If a line is not equal to the JSON file value
          else if(!res){
            html.gotoLine(line);
            line = line + 1;
            
           //Error function with parameters
           //error_note(true, error, line);
            
          }else if(res && check !== null){
            //Code is validated, now save the code
          }
        }
      });
```

```css
#html-editor{
height: 500px; 
}

#run{
font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.5/ace.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.5/ext-language_tools.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="run">Run</button>
<pre id="html-editor">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html&gt;
    &lt;head&gt;
     &lt;title&gt;Introduction to HTML&lt;/title&gt;
    &lt;/head&gt;
    &lt;body&gt;
        &lt;h1&gt;Welcome to Code&lt;/h1&gt;
        &lt;p&gt;Edit and replace with your name&lt;/p&gt;
        
    &lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;<pre>
```